# Saving image on a hard drive with no memory left

Tags: java, image, io, save, hard-drive

I need to know which exception will be raised when i save an image on a drive that have no empty space to hold it, so i can notify the user that the memory is full.
I'm saving images this way:

```
try{
    ThumbPath ="C:/DlApp/Media/Disegni/Thumbnails/"+jLabel_Codice.getText()+".png";

    File outputfile = new File(ThumbPath);
    ImageIO.write(bi, "png", outputfile);
} catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(PanelDialogNuovoOperatore.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
} catch (NullPointerException e){
        ThumbPath = null;
}
```

Any Suggestion?
Thnx in advance for your replies

Comment: IOException - if an error occurs during writing. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/imageio/ImageIO.html

Comment: Thank you nambari. So i can't know what really happened. it just catch any error during writing right?

Comment: I am not sure whether exception message provides any fine grained details or not, but exception you get would be IOException.